# Boost serialization with boost socket fails

Tags: c++, boost-asio, boost-serialization

I'm trying to un-serialize an object passed trough an asio socket but I'm having an error :
"terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::archive::archive_exception'
  what():  input stream error"
when I'm trying to get the data:

server side :

```cpp
int main()
{
...
    std::ostringstream oss;
    Note note(20,20);

    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(oss);
    oa << note;
    std::cout << (char*)&oa << std::endl;
    send_(socket_, (char *)&oa);
}
```

client side :

```cpp
int main()
{
...
    boost::asio::read(socket, receive_buffer, boost::asio::transfer_all(), error);

    std::string myString;

    std::istream(&receive_buffer) >> myString;
    std::istringstream iss(myString);
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(iss); <--- input stream error
    ia >> note;
    std::cout << note.denominateur << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to send the content of ostringstream i.e. string which contains serialized `Note`. Now you are sending bytes of `text_oarchive` instance, which doesn't make any sense for me.

It may look like:

```
  boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(oss);
  oa << note;
  cout << oss.str(); // HERE you get some string which represents serialized Note
  // and content of this string should be sent
  send_(socket_, oss.str().c_str(), oss.str().size());
                 ^^^ content        ^^^ size of content
```

Your `send_` function takes no size parameter? Interesting, for me it should take this param to know how many bytes must be transmitted.

Regarding to the client side:

```
// [1]
boost::asio::read(socket, receive_buffer, boost::asio::transfer_all(), error);
```

because you didn't provide MCVE, I assume in [1] line you create `receive_buffer` as some kind of *dynamic_buffer*, if not and it is just empty string you will read empty string. So deserialization won't work.

Comment: It worked thank you so much. I used send_ that way tho : send_(socket_, oss.str().c_str());

Comment: the send_ function of boost doesn't take a size parameter

Comment: Yes I know, but `send_` takes pointer to `char*` in your code, in this case size of buffer cannot be deduced. If you passed for example `string` there would be no problem, because size of buffer is equal to `string.size()`. The most important thing is now that your code works :)